# Username not following correctly

Tags: java, string, graphics

Hello i'm working on a game and right now i'm trying to have a username follow the character and I have the screen follow the character but when the screen starts to follow the character, the string starts to fly away I have tried everything including making an individual X and Y for it. Here is my code please help:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Play extends BasicGameState {

    private BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage(Core.HEIGHT, Core.WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Animation now, moveUp, moveDown, moveRight, moveLeft;

/*
    Image Up1;
    Image Up2;

    Image Down1;
    Image Down2;

    Image Right1;
    Image Right2;

    Image Left1;
    Image Left2;
*/  
    Image map;
    Image collision;



    boolean exitMenu = false;

    int[] duration = {200, 200};

    int escapeInt = 1;

    int Y = 150;
    int X = 150;

    public String currentUser = "Evan";
    int usernameY;
    int usernameX;

    int camY;
    int camX;

    int WORLD_SIZE_X = 5000;
    int WORLD_SIZE_Y = 5000;
    int VIEWPORT_SIZE_X = 1366;
    int VIEWPORT_SIZE_Y = 768;

    int offsetMaxX = WORLD_SIZE_X - VIEWPORT_SIZE_X;
    int offsetMaxY = WORLD_SIZE_Y - VIEWPORT_SIZE_Y;
    int offsetMinX = 0;
    int offsetMinY = 0;


    public Play(int state) {
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        /*
        Up1 = new Image("res/Up1.png");
        Up2 = new Image("res/Up2.png");

        Down1 = new Image("res/Down1.png");
        Down2 = new Image("res/Down2.png");

        Right1 = new Image("res/Right1.png");
        Right2 = new Image("res/Right2.png");

        Left1 = new Image("res/Left1.png");
        Left2 = new Image("res/Left2.png");
        */

        Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/Up1.png"), new Image("res/Up2.png")};
        Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/Down1.png"), new Image("res/Down2.png")};
        Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/Right1.png"), new Image("res/Right2.png")};
        Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/Left1.png"), new Image("res/Left2.png")};

        moveUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
        moveDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);
        moveLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);
        moveRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
        now = moveDown;


        map = new Image("res/Map.jpg");
        collision = new Image("res/Collision.png");





    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        if(input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_W)) {
            Y -= 1;
            usernameY = Y;

            now = moveUp;
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_S)) {
            Y += 1;
            usernameY = Y;

            now = moveDown;
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_A)) {
            X -= 1;
            usernameX = X;

            now = moveLeft;
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_D)) {
            X += 1;
            usernameX = X;

            now = moveRight;
        }

        if(input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            System.exit(3);
        }

        camX = X - VIEWPORT_SIZE_X / 2;
        camY = Y - VIEWPORT_SIZE_Y / 2;

        if (camX > offsetMaxX){ camX = offsetMaxX; }
        if (camX < offsetMinX){ camX = offsetMinX;}

        if (camY > offsetMaxY){ camY = offsetMaxY; }
        if (camY < offsetMinY){ camY = offsetMinY;}

    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.translate( -camX, -camY);
        map.draw(0,0);
        collision.draw(0, 0);

        now.draw(X, Y);

        g.drawString("X: "+X+"   " + "Y: "+ Y, 20 + camX, 20 + camY);

        g.drawString(currentUser, usernameX + camX, usernameY + camY);

}




    public int getID() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide the link to download (org.newdawn) ?

Comment: have you stepped through with a debugger?  what are the values of X and Y doing when you call g.translate?

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the username relative to the character. Try using `g.drawString(currentUser,  X,  Y);`

You can center it afterwards.

**Note:** it would be better to put this code in a seperate class `Player` wich extends `Animations`. You could give it some methods `walkLeft`, `walkRight`, `jump`,.. and some properties for example an `username`, `hp`, .. This would simplify your game class. And making it easier to understand the player object and his `x` and `y` since you are adjusting all on the same level.